# Gemfile sintax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, passenger

Please help me. I tried run my application in Apacher Phusion passenger enviroment. Here is my Gemfile and error messages. Coul you help me?

```
Web application could not be started
Gemfile syntax error:
   bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
                                       ^
/home/absys/public_html/kornyeken/Gemfile:32: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_end
  gem 'sdoc', require => false
       ^
/home/absys/public_html/kornyeken/Gemfile:32: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
  gem 'sdoc', require => false
             ^ (Bundler::GemfileError)
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:33:in `rescue in eval_gemfile'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:29:in `eval_gemfile'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:9:in `evaluate'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:26:in `build'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb:152:in `definition'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb:115:in `setup'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:245:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:348:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:243:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

**And my gemfile:**
https://bitbucket.org/lehnerviktor/kornyeken/src/90d31a8a2e82ab97ae58c71d36d801360fc0519d/Gemfile?at=master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Gem file has incomplete GROUP block.

It has to be either

UNCOMMENTED

```
group :doc do
  #bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require => false
end
```

Or COMMENTED TOTALLY

```
#group :doc do
  #bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
#  gem 'sdoc', require => false
#end
```

Comment: Thanks you Satya Kalluri!